# Words cognate with race (in the sense of a speed competition)

Tags: cognates

The word race has two types of meanings and I am going to focus on the Norse one. It comes from the PiE root *reh₁s-. Wiktionary has no page or link to non-Germanic cognates and I know that there has to be cognate(s) because of how the comparative method works. Do you have any?

Comment: Hmm... Grimm has no outer-Germanic relations for [rasen (vb.)](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GR00809#XGR00809) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Pfeifer writes:

> **`rasen`** Vb. ‘wütend sein, toben, ungestüm laufen, schnell fahren’,
>
> ahd. `girāsēn` (?, 9. Jh.),
>
> mhd. (selten, vorwiegend md.) `rāsen` ‘toll sein, toben’,
>
> mnd. mnl. `rāsen`, nl. `razen` ‘toll sein, toben, wüten’,
>
> aengl. `rǣsan` ‘stürzen, eilen, angreifen, losstürmen’,
>
> anord. `rāsa` ‘vorwärtsstürzen, ungestüm vorgehen’, schwed. `rasa` ‘toben, wüten’
>
> (westgerm. `*rēsōn`) und (ablautend) anord. schwed. `rasa` ‘gleiten, (ein)stürzen’
>
> sind abgeleitet von
>
> mnd. `rās` ‘heftige Strömung’, aengl. `rǣs` ‘Lauf, Sprung, Ansturm, Angriff’, anord. `rās` ‘Lauf, Fahrt, Sturz, Öffnung’
>
> (daraus entlehnt engl. **`race`** ‘Wettlaufen, -rennen’)
>
> sowie anord. `ras` ‘Eile, Hast’, schwed. `ras` ‘(Ein)sturz, (Erd)rutsch, Ausgelassenheit’.
>
> **Außergerm. vergleichen sich (zu ie. `*rōsā́` ‘Schwung, Wurf’) **
>
> **griech. `erōé͞in` (ἐρωεῖν) ‘schnell laufen, hervorströmen, fließen, strömen’, `erōḗ` (ἐρωή) ‘Schwung, Wucht, Andrang, Wurf’,**
>
> **lat. `rōrāriī` (Plur.) ‘junge, leicht (mit Schleudern) bewaffnete Soldaten’ (als Plänklertruppe),**
>
> **so daß an ie. `*er(ə)s-`, `*rē̌s-` ‘fließen, aufgebracht sein, erregt sein’ (s. ↗irr, ↗Auerhahn) angeknüpft werden kann, wohl eine s-Erweiterung der Wurzel ie. `*er-`, `*or-`, `*r-` ‘sich in Bewegung setzen, erregen, in die Höhe bringen (auch von Bewegungen nach abwärts)’** (wozu auch ↗Reise, ↗rinnen, ↗rennen, ↗rieseln, s. d.).
>
> Zu Beginn der nhd. Zeit sind die Bedeutungen eines irrsinnigen Gebarens und einer übergroßen Geschwindigkeit voll ausgebildet.
>
> Das Part. Präs. `rasend` wird seit dem 18. Jh. in dem steigernden, auch übertreibenden Sinne von ‘in hohem Maße’ gebraucht.

https://www.dwds.de/wb/rasen

Comment: Will you be offended if I edit to add linebreaks?

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer. Please do.

Comment: Gseit getun, chef

Comment: Outside of germanic i mean

Comment: @NumberFile. Greek and Latin cognates are mentioned therein.